# Symfony file type is not validated in OneToMany relation

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a strange, let's call it occurence within the validations of a form.

I have an user entity, which has a OneToMany relation to a Document entity (for file, image, videos etc. uploads). When submitting the form, the 'file' property of the Document entity is not validated.

Let's start by the User Entity, where I built up the relation to the Document Entity:

```
 /**
 * @var Document
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Document", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist"})
 **/
protected $documents;
```

and this user form type for it where i add the documents collection:

```
 ->add('documents', 'collection', array(
       'type' => new DocumentType(),
       'allow_add' => true,
       'by_reference' => false,
       'allow_delete' => true,
       'prototype' => true,
     ))
```

In the setDefaultOptions method of this form type, i activated:

```
'cascade_validation' => true,
```

Now let's head to the Document entity:

```
  /**
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
  */
 class Document
 {

/**
 * @var IntegerType
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $name;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
protected $path;


private $temp;


/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
protected $file;


/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="documents")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * */
protected $user;


/**
 * Sets file.
 *
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    // check if we have an old image path
    if (isset($this->path)) {
        // store the old name to delete after the update
        $this->temp = $this->path;
        $this->path = null;
    } else {
        $this->path = 'initial';
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
        // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
        $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $this->name = $filename;
        $this->path = $filename.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
    // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
    // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
    $this->getFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

    // check if we have an old image
    if (isset($this->temp)) {
        // delete the old image
        unlink($this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->temp);
        // clear the temp image path
        $this->temp = null;
    }
    $this->file = null;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    $file = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    if ($file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // the absolute directory path where uploaded
    // documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
    // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
    return 'uploads/documents';
}
}
```

And its Form type (DocumentType) where I add the file :

```
 $builder
        ->add('file', 'file')
    ;
```

Up to here, it's ok. But when i submit my form, the 'file' field is not validated.

I already tried @Assert\Valid above the field, but it's still not working (I think the cascade_validation replaces this anyway).

Why are the documents not validated ? Has this something to do with the lifecycle callbacks ? I have this "Document Entity" of an offical cookbook entry of Symfony.

Comment: have you: `enable_annotations: true` ?

Comment: yes i've already enabled it

Comment: have you test any validation error? `/** @Assert\False() */ private $x = true;`. And again read another post that your data object should not do any upload logic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28754907/4469738 It's hard to understand your code.

Comment: The Code is from Symfony offical cookbook entry. I've added another field, like your private $x = true. It gets validated, and suddenly, the 'file field' also gets validated. But when i don't have another field than 'file', it does not validate it :/ strange

Comment: * when i don't have another field, that is also added to the DocumentType