# Symfony services --> correct usage?

Tags: symfony, service, controller

first of all I am trying to use services for the first time... (Actually if s.o. could give a short info about how and when and why to use it.. nice ;-) )

But now to my specific case:

I wrote two controllers: 
One for uploading a xlsx file to the server
One for importing the xlsx data to the DB

What I now want to do is to pass the (uploaded)path from the uploading controller to the import controller. am I correct to use the import as a service?

Code looks as the following...

```
class FileUploadController extends Controller

/**
* @Route("/upload", name="upload")
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
*/

public function uploadAction(Request $request){
    $companyid    = $this->getUser()->getCompany();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
        $file = $request->files->get('xls');
        $uploadedURL = '';
        if(($file instanceof UploadedFile) && $file->getError()=='0'){
            if(!($file->getSize()<20000)){
                $originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $name_array = explode('.',$originalName );
                $file_type = $name_array[(sizeof($name_array)-1)];
                $valid_filetypes = array('xls', 'xlsx');
                if(in_array(strtolower($file_type), $valid_filetypes)){

                    $document = new Document();
                    $document->setFile($file);
                    $document->setSubDirectory('uploads');
                    $document->processFile();
                    $uploadedURL=$uploadedURL=$document->getUploadDirectory().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$document->getSubDirectory().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file->getBasename();



                }else{
                    echo "Wrong File Ending";
                }
            }else {
                echo "File to big";
            }

        }else{
            print_r('File Error');
            die;;
        }

        $this->get("dataimport.service")->importIndexAction($uploadedURL);

    }else{


        return $this->render(bla)
```

DataImportController as:

```
class DataImportController extends Controller

 /**
* @param ContainerInterface $container
*/
 public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
 {
  $this->container = $container;
}

/**
* @Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")
*/
public function importIndexAction($path)
{    


  $companyid    = $this->getUser()->getCompany();
  $em           = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $file         = $this->defineFilePathAction($path);
  $reader       = $this->readExcelAction($file);
  $accountarray = $this->getAccountsArrayAction($companyid);
  $this->importAccountsAction($companyid, $reader, $accountarray, $em);

}
....
/**
    * Get a service from the container
    *
    * @param string The service to get
    */
      public function get($service)
      {
        return $this->container->get($service);
      }
```

services.yml

```
services:
dataimport.service:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\DataHandling\DataImportController
    arguments: [@service_container]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ... Are you waiting for something like 'yes' or 'no' ?

Comment: thanks for your answer.... what i expact is that someone tells me if this is a correct way to use services.... or if i am completely wrong.. cause i don't think that if i use it for the first time everything is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony a controller and service is at first just a class. A controller's public method is meant to take an input and generates an `Response` (output) (by the way injecting the `Request` is deprecated, you have to use the current request from the `request_stack`). A service is an object out of the DI container with no constraints at all.

Since the controller's method has to generate and return a response, it's mostly not a good idea to invoke a controller from another controller, because you maybe don't need that response, but only the implementation of the method.

That's also the reason why you should move reusable code to services. A controller should actually only:

- extract data from the request
- call some services
- render a template with the result

Same for Commands. The services are the core of your application. Horizontal communication between controllers or commands is mostly a bad idea (only of course some proxies or wrapper).

Here are some ideas for your code:

1. The action itself is too much unreadable code. If you get the uploaded file via symfony form read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28754907/4469738
2. Don't access the request directly if you use forms. The reason is, that only your builder or `Type` class which creates the form (and the data class), knows the name of the input fields and maps them to a data class. You should just use the data class. Then you get a nice `UploadedFile` object to check everything, but also move the checks to services.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful! So how i use it is wrong right?.. would you recommend joining these two controllers to one?

Comment: The idea of using services is correct :) I edited my post for more ideas.